# Setup ssh server to forward connections

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

Within my network there is currently a computer than handles a bunch of IT repos, all on the 'git' user.
Users can also login on their own accounts to run other programs. Currently they do this on the same machine as the git server. I would like to make this happen on another computer.

I am trying to see if it's possible to make the ssh server the default for port 22 on the router, but forward any connections to the git user on that machine to the old server, where git still is.

That way anyone@ourserver.com logs into the new server, but git@ourserver.com logs into the existing server.

All the machines involved run/will run ubuntu.

I do not want users to have to manually set there git remotes to login via the new computer. that is not a solution. It must be seamless :)

Comment: This isn't a programming related question, and therefore it's offtopic on this site. You should ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com

Comment: @Let_Me_Be disagree. This implies programmatic solution thus it is not offtopic.

Comment: @lig This is a configuration issue.

Comment: thank, i realised it was prob not quite the right place, i wasnt really sure where to ask though... i dont normally use forums much, but i do know of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You may set `SHELL` for user `git` to your own script (in bash or say in python). That will connect to the old server and will act as proxy for this two connections. Of cause you need to deal with users' public keys to forward authentication as well.

Comment: This i like, i will have to give it a try and see if it works, i am thinking i can prob just write a bash scripts that will pipe into a new ssh connection. Bit of searching to find how to get the key passed on.

Answer (score 0):

While @lig offers a server-side solution that requires writing a custom script, you can always do a client-side configuration that'll work out of the box. Assuming you have a recent version of OpenSSH on the desktop (have the -W switch), you can do this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host git.ourserver.com
User git
ProxyCommand ssh -W the.git.server:22 ourserver.com
```

When the user does 'ssh git.ourserver.com' it'll first go to ourserver.com, and then forward the connection. If both servers use the same public key for authentication, and you're using an ssh-agent (or a passwordless ssh key) you won't have to authenticate twice.

This *should* work when you push/pull via git, so long as your git's "remote" exactly matches the "Host" in your `~/ssh/config` file.

Comment: This seems harder than changing git remote url for me.

Comment: I read his situation and it sounded like this: he forwards port 22 on his router to one host, which he doesn't want to host git anymore. In order to use the same IP/port for ssh to get to another server behind the router's IP, that default host for ssh has to forward the connection.

Comment: I have used that style of ssh config for a while, but in this case its not the solution because i want the forwarding to be transparent to the users.